# How to set an onClickListener in android for anywhere except an element on the screen

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

So, I have an activity in android with an attach button on the Action bar.

When I click the button, two floating action buttons appear (one for image, one for camera). When I click the button again, they disappear.

Now, I want to make it such that if the user clicks anywhere on the screen that isn't one of those two FABs, that they will disappear. I already have the action / commands to make them disappear; however, I am looking for how to set up an onClickListener for the whole screen EXCEPT the region covered by the two FABs.

Comment: There is no universal "anywhere but there" spot for such listeners. Add an `OnClickListener` to the top-level container, as touch events get passed to parents if children do not consume them.

Answer (score 0):

I was solved the same scenario you can compare it with my scenario and can apply on yours :

my scenario : Hide the keyboard on touch of screen any where accept EditText.

Solution : Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    setupUI(findViewById(R.id.scrolview)); // === scrolview is container of all views inside it ===
```

}

```
 public void setupUI(View view) {
    //Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if(!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(SignupActivity.this);

                findViewById( R.id.first_linear_layout ).requestFocus();

                return false;
            }

        });
    }
    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

            setupUI(innerView);
        }
    }
}
 public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```